# Eclipse program arguments, pass literal variable names

Tags: eclipse, variables, escaping

I am writing a program which expects command line arguments of the form

```
-foo ${foo}
```

However, `${name}` is Eclipse’s notation for variables. Passing the above command line argument causes Eclipse to look for an internal variable named `foo` and inserting that instead of the `${foo}` variable specification before running the program.

What is the proper way of escaping `${foo}` so Eclipse will pass it literally, rather than trying to expand it?

Comment: Should have been: backslash was my first guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR:** `$\{foo}`

The escape character for Eclipse is `\`; prepending this will cause Eclipse to pass the following character literally.

Of a string resembling a variable specification, only the opening brace needs to be escaped in order to pass the whole thing literally.

Escaping `$` and `}` is not needed but will do no harm – `$\{foo}`, `\$\{foo}` and `\$\{foo\}` will all result in `${foo}` being passed to the program.